# How to have a delay occur POST-emission?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactivex

I would like for every emission from my Observable to have a delay occur AFTER its emission. i.e. For every item emitted from `Observable.fromIterable(listOf(1,2,3))` I would like a variable/dynamic delay AFTERWARDS.

i.e. given a list of timers or delays `[3, 5, 10]`, I would like for the following timeline to occur with my observable:

`1 -> Wait 3 seconds -> 2 -> Wait 5 seconds -> 3 -> Wait 10 seconds`

Please note that this is NOT the same as:

`Wait 3 seconds -> 1 -> Wait 5 seconds -> 2 -> Wait 10 seconds -> 3`

which can be easily achieved with .zip + .delay or Observable.Timer

Comment: By "given a list of timers or delays `[3, 5, 10]`" do you already have these timers created in a list, ready to go (how?) or do you only have the values and want to use them as delays? Is the list of delays and the list of values (from the other observable) somehow fixed and/or known ahead of time? What have you tried so far and what were the problems with your attempts?

Comment: Yes the list is known ahead of time.

Regarding what I have tried, I am able to produce the example output I want by abusing the subscription block and placing delays there while recursively entering the chain with a dwindling list from before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `zip()` is the right way to go. When you want the delay **after** the first value is emitted, then you can use [`startWith()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#startWith-T-) to add a zero delay for the first combination. The code might look like this:

```
Observable<Integer> values = Observable.fromArray(1,2,3,4,5);
Observable<Long> delays = Observable.fromArray(300L, 400L, 500L, 600L);
    
Observable<Integer> delayedValues = values.zipWith(
    delays.startWith(0L),
    new BiFunction<Integer, Long, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer apply(Integer v, Long d) throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(d);
            return v;
        }
    }
);
System.out.println("Begin subscribing");
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
delayedValues.subscribe(v -> {
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long diff = currentTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("["+diff+"] "+v);
});
System.out.println("After subscribing");
```

This will generate the following output:

```
Begin subscribing
[35] 1
[336] 2
[736] 3
[1236] 4
[1836] 5
After subscribing
```

As you see, the first value is printed immediately, following by a 300ms delay for the next value until you reached the end.